# Managing multiple versions of files on nodes

Tags: files

The client needs to be able to upload numerous files to each node. They would like only the new versions of files to be searchable/in the search results and for the previous document versions to be versioned, available on the page but not searchable.

I was thinking of adding a file field type to the content type with unlimited number of values. But I cannot figure out a way to disable the search from searching through the previous version.

Any tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using apache solr attachments?

Answer (score 1):

You could try either [Revision All](http://drupal.org/project/revision_all)

> Revision All allows for centralized management of content type
>   revisioning. Revisioning can be turned on/off individually by type or
>   enabled for all simultaneously. There is also support for enabling
>   automatic revisioning of future content types and the disabling of the
>   "create new revision" checkbox on node and/or content type forms.

or [Document](http://drupal.org/project/document) modules

> A Document Management System for Drupal.

Features:

1. Complete integration with Drupal node system. This module adds a custom Node Type, Document. Each Document you create is a Drupal node, and hence enjoys all features available to a node.
2. Support for Document revisions/versioning - This module allows you to maintain multiple versions/revisions of the same document.
3. Views 2 Integration - The custom fields added by the module to the Document node type are accessible in Views, plus the module provides some useful out-of-the box Views.
4. Theming support
5. Searching - The documents being nodes are fully indexable by the Drupal search system. In addition, the module provides its own custom search for Documents.
6. A couple of blocks are available for document search that can be placed flexibly in your theme layout.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did a fair bit of research but cannot work out how to prevent all versions of the documents apart from the latest from being displayed in the search results. @Nikhil-M

Answer (score 0):

This information appears out-dated.  Please review the media initiative for Drupal 8:

https://dri.es/a-plan-for-media-management-in-drupal-8
https://dri.es/an-update-on-the-media-initiative-for-drupal-8-4-8-5

Also check out Lightning:
https://www.drupal.org/project/lightning

Thunder:
https://dri.es/thunder-a-drupal-distribution-for-publishers

and NP8:
https://www.md-systems.ch/en/blog/md-systems/2016/08/09/md-systems-introduced-np8-to-the-big-apple